# Retrieving the value of a hidden ID field that has been filled by a autocomplete call for use in another autocomplete call

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using DMX Zones AutoComplete Extension to create several autocompletes on the same page and in one of them I want to use the value of a hidden ID field that is populated by the very first autocomplete which enables the selection of a Brand.

The jQuery code I have looks like this:

jQuery('#ColorCode_0').autocomplete('add-a-model-color-php-1.php', {
    opacity : .9,
    delay : 100,
    minChars : 1,
    idField : 'color',
    hiddenIdField : 'color_0',
    fxShow : { type:'slide' },
    fxHide : { type:'slide' },
    extraParams: { pkBrand: $('input[name="pkBrand_0"]').val() }
  });

I can see that the hidden ID field is populated after the call to the brands file but when I submit the ColorCode autocomplete pkBrand is always empty like so: add-a-model-color-php-1.php?q=b&limit=10&pkBrand=

How can I access pkBrand_0 so that I can pass the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This updated code pulls the value of the hidden ID field

```
jQuery('#ColorCode_0').autocomplete('/_plugins/ajax/add-a-model-color-php-1.php',
{
  opacity : .9,
  delay : 100,
  minChars : 1,
  idField : 'color',
  hiddenIdField : 'color_0',
  fxShow : { type:'slide' },
  fxHide : { type:'slide' },
  extraParams: { 
    pkBrand: function(){ return $('#pkBrand_0').val(); }
  }
});
```